# Add the count value of occurrences of different values in a table as a new column to the table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the following table, how can I count the number of occurrences of different User IDs and make a new table that has the User IDs and the count values only.

[image]

For example, I want a new table that looks like this:

```
User    count
5173     3
5175     2
5181     1
5183     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [value_counts()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) method:

```
df.User.value_counts().to_frame('count').reset_index().rename(columns=dict(index='User'))
```

or if you want to keep `User` column as an index:

```
df.User.value_counts().to_frame('count')
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way that user IDs are also a column not index values?

Comment: Thank you very much. I wish you could keep both of your answers so that other people could also use it.